# Send two objects with $http.post in AngularJS while uploading a file with some data

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to send a request from my js file to my controller in angular.

What I am doing is

```
var fd = new FormData();
    for (var i = 0; i < file.length; i++) {
        fd.append("file", file[i]);
    }

$http.post('Employees/', $scope.Employee, fd, {
        transformRequest: angular.identity,
        headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined }
    }).success(function (data) {
        $scope.AddEditEmployee = false;
        getEmployees();
    }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
    });
```

The problem i face here is that I get the values of $scope.Employees but the fd comes empty. This is a part of uploading file with some data in AngularJS

Code in my controller is

```
    public class EmployeesController: ApiController
{
    EmployeeDM objEmpManager = new EmployeeDM(BaseDapper.CreateInstance());
[Route("Employees/")]
    [HttpPost]
    public void Post(EmployeeBO obj_emp)
    //public void Post(EmployeeBO obj_emp1, EmployeeBO obj_emp)
    {
        try
        {
            var httpRequest = HttpContext.Current.Request;
            string image_names = string.Empty;
            string ResumeName = string.Empty;
            string resumePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/Uploads/Resume/");
            if (httpRequest.Files.Count > 0)
            {
                string resume_full_path = string.Empty;
                for (int i = 0; i < httpRequest.Files.Count; i++)
                {
                    var postedFile = httpRequest.Files[i];
                    ResumeName = postedFile.FileName;
                    resume_full_path = resumePath + obj_emp.name + ResumeName;
                    postedFile.SaveAs(resume_full_path);
                    image_names += resume_full_path.ToString() + ',';
                    obj_emp.resume = resume_full_path;
                    if (obj_emp.employee_id > 0)
                    {
                        objEmpManager.UpdateEmployee(obj_emp);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        objEmpManager.SaveEmployee(obj_emp);
                    }
                }
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        { }

    }}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
var fd = new FormData();
for (var i = 0; i < file.length; i++) {
    fd.append("file", file[i]);
}

for (var key in $scope.Employee) {
        fd.append(key, $scope.Employee[key]);
        alert($scope.Employee[key]);
    }

$http.post('Employees/', fd, {
        headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined }
    }).success(function (data) {
        $scope.AddEditEmployee = false;
        getEmployees();
    }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
    });
```

From backend you need to remove object as parameter and find that from form of request.

```
    public void Post(){ 
EmployeeBo obj = new EmployeeBo();
obj.key= HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["Key"];

.........
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer... I tried with your solution... 
I think I am almost there.. What problem I am facing now is that I am able to see a Form value as "Employee" in my backend.. But how to get the values that were in $scope.Employee.

Actually I am a beginner so my question can be simple or without meaning..

Comment: Can you please debug that and check which value inside that and please give me here so i can give you better solutions

Comment: Thank you for your help... I added some loop and got the values at my backend respective to each key

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$http({
method:"POST",
url:"Employees/",
transformRequest: angular.identity,
headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined },
data:{obj_emp1:$scope.Employee , obj_emp:fd }
}).then(
function success(data){
$scope.AddEditEmployee = false;
getEmployees();}, 
function error(data){
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution..
I tried to do this but it fails to go to the controller. Reporting error
 POST http://localhost:1830/Employees/ 415 (Unsupported Media Type)

Comment: would  you change the definition of your Post method? post method must have two parameters.

Comment: no... tried using your solution with both of my code blocks in controller file...

Comment: remove "headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined }" from $http or try application/json instead of undefined.